# SQL server 2008 , conditional select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help me to form this query.

I have a table like this:

```
Row Product   Role            
-------------------
1   ABC-1     Self
2   ABC-2     Self
3   ABC-2     Joint
4   ABC-3     Self
5   ABC-3     Joint
6   ABC-4     Self
```

I want to fetch only those  product rows where Role is Self only. In other words from the given table the SQL query should output only rows 1 & 6. Output should look like this

```
Row Product   Role            
-------------------
1   ABC-1     Self
6   ABC-4     Self
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks. I have a query running with a bunch of joins fetching data and this would be sub query to that. Somewhere I am missing the connection and this is not retrieving any data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                 WHERE Product = t.Product
                 AND Role <> 'Self');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
Select  *
From    YourTable   T
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    YourTable   T1
    Where   T.Product = T1.Product
    And     T1.[Role] <> 'Self'
)
And    T.[Role] = 'Self'
```